# Why would DateTime.Now.Date formats differ between systems?

Tags: c#, datetime

Why on one system would the default time be 12:00:00 and on another 00:00:00

```
DateTime.Now.Date
```

Starting with string in a web ui, passing thru Nhibernate to SQL Server 2005.
For example 6/10/2009 is entered in a textbox on a web server by the time it is caught in sql profiler I see 2 different times

00:00:00 on my local system (XP), Dev, Test, Staging (2003)
12:00:00 on Prod (2003)

Thanks for the quick replies

Regional settings and DateTime format are the same.

Comment: Are we sure this is the Challenge of the Week?

Comment: I think by box he means a computer and not a textbox!

Comment: What is the full value being returned?
Is this a formatting issue or are different times being displayed?
How much of the system (web, Nhibernate & SQL Server) are on different machines?
How do you ensure that your staging and production environments are identical?
Can you track the value at different points in the system to see where it changes?

Comment: 2 machines web and sql... I will need to turn up logging.  Funeral beats prod issues.. Thanks for ideas.  Back in a few hours

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regional/display settings for date/time formats

Comment: A vague answer to a vague question. Could you expand on how these would produce that type of behavior?

Comment: more fun to make people guess

Comment: tvanfosson: the time (and date) formats can be configured to display on a per machine basis.  If the machiens were configured to be in different timezones 'now' would also be different.

Comment: SQL Profile is showing time is back to 00:00:00 today...  adding a globalization tag to system.web in prod and will continue to investigate. Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 5):

In the control panel, you can define the way it displays in regional settings:

H:mm:ss -> 24 hours you will see 00:00

h:mm:ss -> 12 hours format with am/pm you will see 12:00 am

Comment: I hope you right!  Hard to believe we haven't caught this before... Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's always midnight, the display might be affected by the machine's local culture settings.

You might be interested in the [Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html) for a whole slew of other things that can be affected by culture, like parsing doubles, formatting dates and times, etc.

Answer (score 3):

12 hour vs 24 hour clock